# cannot import name balanced_accuracy_score

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using anaconda and running a script on spyder. When I call

```
import from sklearn.metrics balanced_accuracy_score
```

I get the error: "cannot import name balanced_accuracy_score "

Why is this particular metric not being imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import from` is not valid syntax for Python, the pattern is

`import <package>`  - for entire package

or

`from <package> import <module>` - only specific module in package

you want the latter, try:

```
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score
```

Comment: what is the complete `import` statement giving you that error? and what package/module(s) are you trying to import?

Comment: `import from sklearn.metrics balanced_accuracy_score`. I'm trying to import [sklearn's balanced_accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score)

Comment: You're import syntax is incorrect (same as in the OP question), we can't use `import from ...`, instead use `from` <package> `import` <module> ..., try `from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score`

Comment: Sorry, copy paste mistake. My import statement is actually `from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score`. Problem as I described. Anyway, maybe it's added onyl in 0.20

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183744/discussion-between-davedwards-and-alaa-m).