# cannot import name 'balanced_accuracy_score'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter

I need to use balanced_accuracy_score function. When I type `from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score` I get the Import Error. A version of `scikit-learn` on my computer is 0.21.0. I haven't trouble with importing the other functions from `sklearn`. I tried to reinstall `numpy` (now 1.16.3) and `pip` (now 19.1.1). What else could you advise me to check?

Comment: Can you please include the error message you get in your question? That would help a lot to analyze the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919980/cannot-import-name-balanced-accuracy-score

Comment: Does `import sklearn` work?  How about `import sklearn.metrics`?

Comment: In Jupyter ImportError is `cannot import name 'balanced_accuracy_score' from 'sklearn.metrics' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)`, in command line long message, briethly it is: `DLL load failed`. I tried run `import sklearn.metrics` and in Jupyter it's OK, but in command line I get the same Import Error.

Comment: `import sklearn` and `import numpy` behave like `import sklearn.metrics`: in Jupyter work, in the command line don't (`DLL load failed`).

Comment: It's strange, that the library works differently in Jupyter and in the command line. Even version has different values. `pip list` gives 0.21.0 and Jupyter command `sklearn.__version__` shows 0.19.2. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: It is not of course that the library behaves differently, it is that your Jupyter notebook probably runs in a different environment, where you have an older version of scikit-learn (0.19.2), which [does not include](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics) `balanced_accuracy_score`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: 'balanced\_accuracy' is not a valid scoring value in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349331/valueerror-balanced-accuracy-is-not-a-valid-scoring-value-in-scikit-learn)